# Query of concatenation on Access

Tags: ms-access, group-by, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

I have an access file of all the tasks of the employees.

I want to make a query of `group by` on two columns:

- Employee Name
- Date

Sometimes I have couple of tasks each day and I want them to concatenate them into one cell.

I tried to do group by with "&" operator but it is not working.

Example:

[image: Example data]

I would truly appreciate ideas and solutions.

Comment: You need custom VBA function to concatenate in `MS-Access`.

Comment: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

Comment: @Harun24hr - great suggestion. Looks like it would work great for OP - limit of  255 characters shouldn't be an issue